# Fetch Data from Stored Procedures using PDO (error:"Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object")

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

I want to fetch data from two tables on same php. I have created two stored procedures and calling on PHP like below:

***CALLING STORED PROCEDURE 1***

```
$result = $dbh->query('CALL getEnqbyID("'.$enquiry_id.'")'); 
while ($data= $result->fetchObject())    
{
$data['name'];
}
```

***CALLING STORED PROCEDURE 2***

```
$result2 = $dbh->query('CALL getMaster("'.$enquiry_id.'")'); 
while ($data2= $result2->fetchObject())  
{
$data2['description'];
}
```

While calling it shows error "Call to a member function fetchObject() on a non-object". Every time I tried to use two SELECT on same PHP it will always shows this Error.

Can you please provide the solution of How Can I Call & Display multiple SELECT procedures on same PHP?

Regards 
Adnan

Comment: your query failed; check for errors

Comment: [You need to call PDOStatement::nextRowset()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call) after the first one

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I already checked the queries, they are working properly. As per you suggestion I used following code:

   $result = $dbh->query('CALL getAllEnquiries("'.$company.'")'); 
  
   $data= $result->fetchAll();
   print_r($data);
  
 
  
   
   $result1 = $dbh->query('CALL getCountries()');
    $result1= $dbh->nextRowset(); 
   $data2= $result1->fetchAll();
   print_r($data2);

"Call to undefined method PDO::nextRowset()"

**Can you pls provide me the syntax of nextRowset()..so that i can know how to use?**